# Uncaught Error: Container is not defined (Google Charts + jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api, google-chart

Гугл предлагает рисовать графики вот так:

```
var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
```

Я подумал, что если у меня jQuery, то почему бы `document.getElementById('chart_div')` не заменить на `$('#chart_div')`? Всё бы хорошо было, если бы оно работало. Консоль пишет:

> Uncaught Error: Container is not defined

В чём дело?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что `$('#chart_div')` возвращает jQuery-объект, массив содержащий или 0 или 1 элемент (т.е. уже получается вложенность и можно попробовать обратиться `$('#chart_div')[0]`), а `document.getElementById('chart_div')` сразу возвращает ссылку на [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element)-объект.

Comment: Что ж.. Действительно работает. Спасибо) А вообще такая вещь логична или лучше классический JS оставить?

Comment: Ну это уж как вам удобней, писать можно как угодно - главное грамотно :) Если у вас jQuery используется повсеместно и большая часть кода с использованием этой библиотеки - то можно сделать выборку через неё. Приводите весь код к одному стилю.